# Issues with pointers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following code in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Exercise *exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithNibName:@"Exercise" bundle:nil]; //Makes new exercise object.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text; // Retrieves the string of the selected cell.

    exerciseView.exerciseName.text = str;

    NSLog(@"%@",exerciseView.exerciseName.text);

    [self presentModalViewController:exerciseView animated:YES];
}
```

In this, I try to take the text of the selected cell, and set the IBOutlet UILabel exerciseName to that string.

My method compiles, but when I run the NSLog, which prints the textvalue of the UILabel after setting it to str, it returns null. I feel like this is a pointer problem, but can't seem to grasp it. Can anyone clarify things?

Comment: and when you NSLog str you don't get null? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Please see my comment in your other similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the half-initialized view controller.  Need to let it get built before you init the contents of a subview.

Exercise.h

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *theExerciseName;  // assuming ARC

- (id)initWithExerciseName:(NSString *)theExerciseName;
```

Exercise.m

```
@synthesize theExerciseName=_theExerciseName;

- (id)initWithExerciseName:(NSString *)theExerciseName {

    self = [self initWithNibName:@"Exercise" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        self.theExerciseName = theExerciseName;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    exerciseName.text = self.theExerciseName;
}
```

Call that new initializer from your didSelect method.

```
Exercise *exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithExerciseName:str];
```

But please get that str by using the logic within cellForRowAtIndexPath, not by calling it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask what this line means? @synthesize theExerciseName=_theExerciseName;

Comment: Sure - that creates the getter and setter for the property, and gives it an alias so it doesn't collide with stack variables and params (see how the init param has the same name, but no compiler warning).